# What should I do if I don't know which answer should I accept?

Tags: support

I have asked a question like `Is better A solution or B solution?` and have some answers. Some of them suggest A solution, some of them suggest B solution and also giving arguments for the solution which they are suggesting.

However, I still don't know which one is better and which of them will be implemented <=> I can't decide which answer is the best one. What should I do?

- I should accept the answer which I like the most (even it is not absolutely correct).
- I should accept the answer which has the most votes (even it is not absolutely correct).
- I should wait and accept answer which will be implemented (If any, what should I do?).
- I should write my own answer because I have implemented half of the first answer and half of the second answer and accept my own answer.
- I should wait for the better answer. (If won't come any, what should I do?)
- I should leave the question with unaccepted answer forever, if nothing will be changed.
- Something else...?

Note: I understand all of the answers.

Comment: You question was probably opinion based then, and should be closed as off-topic at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why would it be opinion based?  Determining which is the *best* answer of multiple *objectively correct* answers is subjective, but that doesn't make the question primarily opinion based.  Even objective questions involve subjectivity in determining the quality of the answer.

Comment: @Servy Hard to tell without a concrete example.

Comment: @Akarienta Not that it matters all that much in this case, but why are you not asking on UX's meta instead, if you have a question involving that site?

Comment: @gnat The OP didn't say he doesn't understand the answer.  He has in fact indicated that he does understand the answers.

Comment: @Servy OP did say "I can't decide which answer is the best one"

Comment: @gnat That doesn't mean he doesn't understand them.  The fact that he says he came up with a solution that involves using both solutions implies that he understands both fairly well.

Comment: @Akarienta Well, what's the better pattern to use for the checkboxes initial state, totally depends on the actual use case you want to cover. So I'd consider it being too broad or opinion based.

Comment: @Servy I am sorry I thought that the system is the same for the whole StackExchange. Should I move this question?

Comment: @Akarienta In this specific case, it's probably fine, because the question is really not site specific at all, but in the future, you should generally post questions on the site meta corresponding to the content in question.

Comment: @Servy OK. Thank you for the clarification, I will.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have described the use case.

Comment: @Akarienta _"I have described the use case. "_ Not clearly enough with all  context necessary for my taste.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Some thoughts:

> I should accept the answer which I like the most (even it is not absolutely correct).

I'd go for this personally. If you feel that you like an answer, and that answer is good & correct and helped you, then I would accept it.

> I should accept the answer which has the most votes (even it is not absolutely correct).

IMHO, No. If you feel that an answer is not correct or only partially correct, you should probably not accept it. Don't just do what everyone else does or thinks is good or correct, choose what *you* think is correct.

> I should wait and accept answer which will be implemented (If any, what should I do?).

You will probably implement the answer which you like the most, so look at point 1. Waiting is **always** a good idea, as an answer which is better than the current ones may come. Don't wait forever though.

> I should write my own answer because I have implemented half of the first answer and half of the second answer and accept my own answer.

Also a good idea. If there where multiple partial answers and you had to combine them to get something useful, then you should write your own which combines all the information. This will also be useful to future readers of your question. You can also write your own answer and *not* accept it, which might also be good.

> I should wait for the better answer. (If won't come any, what should I do?)

As I said, waiting is **always** good. If no better answer comes, choose one of the other options you listed..

> I should leave the question with unaccepted answer forever, if nothing will be changed.

Nah. It really helps other people if there is an accepted answer.

---

- Don't forget to upvote any other answers which you found helpful.
- Also, you can also change which answer you have accepted at any time.

---

**Disclaimer:** Everything I wrote here is my own opinion.

Comment: And oh: Don't accept an answer before you've read it!

Comment: Remember that you can always change your accept vote. Feel free to wait for more/better answers, but you aren't locked in (note that accepting *does* decrease the probability of someone putting in a new answer though).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Forgot to put that about changing accept vote in,  Added.

Answer (score 6):

Any of the options you listed are acceptable.

It's *your* decision to make; we can't make it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone's motive for accepting an answer is different. By general rule-of-thumb, I will accept an answer the helped me eventually solve my problem, even if the answer doesn't 100% answer my initial question.

You can change your accepted answer at any time, so don't feel like you're locking into one specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Something else...?*

If there really is no difference between how helpful Answer A and Answer B are (equally helpful to you, equally helpful to others, neither went into more detail than the other, etc.) you could just accept the one that was posted first and then up-vote the other.